# CiviRules for adding tag to contact do not work

Tags: civirules

I am using CiviCRM 5.39.0 and CiviRules 2.29 (so pretty up to date) but I have no success to implement a rule in CiviRules for adding a tag to some contact when the total amount of his contributions is greater that 0.

After entering the contribution, the system saves the contribution, but when I edit the corresponding rule, I see the rule has not been triggered and the tag is not applied, even after waiting a while.

I tried with a delay and without any delay. The rule is enabled and the cron jobs are running. I am eager to know if I misconfigured something or if this is a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Rule seemed to work fine but perhaps it misses a nuance you need:

- Contribution is added
- Linked Condition(s)
- Condition = Total Contributed Amount
- Description = Total amount all time (with status: Completed) >= 1
- Linked Action(s) = Add Tag to Contact = Volunteer

(The above will be viewable at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/civirule/form/rule?reset=1&action=update&id=1 for a few hours till that site gets rebuilt)

Comment: I will try your flavor of the rule and perhaps try to modify it to suit my needs. Anyway, access is denied to me for https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/civirule/form/rule?reset=1&action=update&id=1

Comment: user and pw are both demo which is explained on the home page at https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: If I create a rule (without delay) and introduce a new contribution, will I see immediately the tag appear into my contacts summary, or do I have to wait "some time" (which is very frustrating for the productivity)?

Comment: It works on the demo site, but I just discovered that the demo site has version 2.31 installed of the CiviRules extension. Mine was 2.29... I was thinking I was up to date since I just upgraded the day before. I am eager to see if the last update fixes this problem.

Comment: OK, it works with version 2.31. I have to refresh the contact page to see the tag appear.